# Can I add a constraint to multiple boolean columns so that at least one must be true?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table in a postgresql 9.3 database that lists clients and the payment types they accept as booleans. A client can accept multiple payment types but they have to accept at least one payment type. So as an example:

Table format:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| clients | paymentType1 | paymentType2 | paymentType3 | 
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| client1 | true         | true         | false        |
| client2 | true         | false        | true         |
| client3 | false        | false        | false        |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

Clients 1 and 2 are valid, client 3 is not valid as they have no payment types. Is there a way to write a constraint to enforce this - so that for any row, at least one of those paymentType booleans must be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if any of them are true in a check constraint:

```
alter table tablename   
add constraint const_name check (paymentType1 or paymentType2 or paymentType3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add the following check constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE yourTable   
ADD CONSTRAINT payment_cnstr CHECK (
    GREATEST(paymentType1, paymentType2, paymentType3) = true
);
```

The `GREATEST()` function above will only return `true` if at least one of the 3 columns have a `true` value.

Answer (score 0):

The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html) has full information on multi-column constraints.

The constraint should be:

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    client0 bool,
    client1 bool,
    client2 bool,
    CHECK((client0 OR client1 OR client2) = true)
);

insert into clients(client0,client1,client2)
values (true, true, false);

insert into clients(client0,client1,client2)
values (false, false, false);
```

The second insert will fail.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ip9vt1TbBj2ahsMKdzGKYY/3)